# Multithreading alternative to mutex in parallel_for

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, mutex, ppl

I'm fairly new to C++, therefore please pardon if this is a stupid question, but I didn't find good example of what I'm looking for on the internet.

Basically I'm using a parallel_for cycle to find a maximum inside a 2D array (and a bunch of other operations in between). First of all I don't even know if this is the best approach, but given the length of this 2D array, I though splitting the calculations would be faster.

My code:

```
vector<vector<double>> InterpU(1801, vector<double>(3601, 0));
Concurrency::parallel_for(0, 1801, [&](int i) {

    long k = 0; long l = 0;
    pair<long, long> Normalized;
    double InterpPointsU[4][4];
    double jRes;
    double iRes = i * 0.1;
    double RelativeY, RelativeX;
    int p, q;

    while (iRes >= (k + 1) * DeltaTheta) k++;
    RelativeX = iRes / DeltaTheta - k;
    for (long j = 0; j < 3600; j++)
    {
        jRes = j * 0.1;
        while (jRes >= (l + 1) * DeltaPhi) l++;
        RelativeY = jRes / DeltaPhi - l;
        p = 0;
        for (long m = k - 1; m < k + 3; m++)
        {
            q = 0;
            for (long n = l - 1; n < l + 3; n++)
            {
                Normalized = Normalize(m, n, PointsTheta, PointsPhi);
                InterpPointsU[p][q] = U[Normalized.first][Normalized.second];
                q++;
            }
            p++;
        }
        InterpU[i][j] = bicubicInterpolate(InterpPointsU, RelativeX, RelativeY);
        if (InterpU[i][j] > MaxU)
        {
            SharedDataLock.lock();
            MaxU = InterpU[i][j];
            SharedDataLock.unlock();
        }
    }
    InterpU[i][3600] = InterpU[i][0];
});
```

You can see here that I'm using a `mutex` called `SharedDataLock` to protect multiple threads accessing the same resource. `MaxU` is a variable that should only containe the maximum of the `InterpU` vector.
The code works well, but since I'm having speed performance problem, I began to look into `atomic` and some other stuff.

Is there any good example on how to modify a similar code to make it faster?

Comment: There is no need to have shared `MaxU` variable. Each thread should find the maximum among it's vector range and then you need to find a maximum among thread results.

Comment: hava a look at `std::atomic`. It is another tool for synchronisation.

Comment: You code is not complete, please post a full example describing your problem... Anyway, you could avoid the lock by using atomic operations.

Comment: Have you considered using a `combinable` for `MaxU`? i.e each thread has its own maximum value, which is later combined using `max`.

Comment: @VTT Well in the end I need to have a single vector containing all the data AND a maximum to normalize it with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by VTT, you can simply find the local maximum of each thread, and merge those afterwards With use of `combinable`:

```
Concurrency::combinable<double> CombinableMaxU;
Concurrency::parallel_for(0, 1801, [&](int i) {
    ...
        CombinableMaxU.local() = std::max(CombinableMaxU.local(), InterpU[i][j]);
}
MaxU = std::max(MaxU, CombinableMaxU.combine(std::max<double>));
```

Note that your current code is actually **wrong** (unless `MaxU` is atomic), you read `MaxU` outside of the lock, while it can be written simultaneously by other threads. Generally, you must not read a value that is being written to simultaneously unless **both** sides are protected by atomic semantics or locks and memory fences. A reason is that a variable access may very well consist of multiple memory accesses, depending on how the type is supported by hardware.

But in your case, you even have a classic race condition:

```
MaxU == 1
  Thread a                 |   Thread b
InterpU[i][j] = 3          | InterpU[i][j] = 2
if (3 > MaxU)              |  if (2 > MaxU)
SharedDataLock.lock();     | SharedDataLock.lock();
(gets the lock)            | (waiting for lock)
MaxU = 3                   | ...
SharedDataLock.unlock();   | ...
...                        | (gets the lock)
                           | MaxU = 2
                           | SharedDataLock.unlock();
MaxU == 2
```

[Locks are hard.](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf)

You can also use an atomic and [compute the maximum on that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16190791/620382). However, I would guess<sup>1</sup> that it still doesn't perform well inside the loop<sup>2</sup>, and outside the loop it doesn't matter whether you use atomics or locks.

<sup>1: When in doubt, don't guess - measure!</sup>

<sup>2: Just because something is atomic and supported by hardware, doesn't mean it is as efficient as accessing local data. First, atomic instructions are often much more costly than their non-atomic counterparts, second you have to deal with very bad cache effects, because cores/caches will fight for the ownership of the data. While atomics may be more elegant in many cases (not this one IMHO), reduction is faster most of the time.</sup>

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you should be accessing and assigning `CombinableMaxU.local()` in the loop. Also, you can probably finish with just `MaxU = CombinableMaxU.combine(std::max<double>);`, assuming its prior value doesn't matter.

Comment: @Hasturkun forgot about the `.local()`, thanks. TBH I am not very familiar with PPL, though it seems quite intuitive. I wanted my answer to be idiomatic, rather than the generic manual solution I used before the edit. From the question I don't know whether the prior value of `MaxU` matters, so I just use a semantically equivalent code.

Comment: @Zulan, I don't understand how the current code is wrong, since no matter what MaxU contains the absolute maximum... I actually wouldn't care the order in which the maximum is compared with its previous value... Anyway, your answer is very much appreciated and looks exactly what I was searching for. Thanks for having taught me something new!

Comment: @Noldor130884 I added a more detailed explanation about the various reasons why your current code is wrong in my answer.

Comment: @Zulan sorry to bother again, but neither `MaxU = CombinableMaxU.combine(std::max<double>);` or `MaxU = std::max(MaxU, CombinableMaxU.combine(std::max<double>));` are working. Am I missing something? How do I have to declare MaxU?

Comment: In what way do they not work? You haven't shown how `MaxU` is declared, but I assumed `double`.

Comment: Yes it is: funny thing though, if I write "plus" instead of "max" it does work. It says that the arguments of the function are not those expected

Comment: Any chance you have an excess pair of `()` there? It's `combine(std::max<double>)`, but `combine(std::min<double>())`. While I can't test myself, this is [reportedly working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10365865/620382), although [sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22943575/620382) `combine([](double left, double right){ return std::max<double>left, right);})` is suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149486/discussion-between-noldor130884-and-zulan).

Comment: Solved it by using a template max function created by myself: